# Does $a \circ b = a$ imply $b$ is the identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two morphisms in category $C$ satisfying the following equation:
$a \circ b = a$.

Does it follow that $b$ is the identity morphism?

Obviously, it it true when $a$ is mono. But I doubt it is true in general and can't find a counterexample.

Comment: No. That will follow if $a$ is a monomorphism ($a$ is cancellable on the  left), but in general. (It may also hold even if $a$ is not a monomorphism, but again, not in general).

Answer (score 6):

As a simple class of counterexamples, there are plenty of non-identity functions $f:X\to X$ with $f\circ f=f$. Such as
$$
f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\\
f(x)=0
$$
But yes, for mono $a$ it does follow, as we are given $a\circ b=a\circ\operatorname{Id}$, and this by definition of mono gives $b=\operatorname{Id}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be any category with a [terminal object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/terminal+object) $x$. Let $y$ be an object in $C$, $a\colon y\rightarrow x$ be the unique morphism from $y$ to $x$ and then for any $b\colon y\rightarrow y$ we will have $a\circ b=a$, because both are morphisms $y\rightarrow x$ and there only is one such morphism. But of course $y$ can have many non-identity endomorphisms $b$ (for an explicit example of this occurring, take $C=\mathbf{Set}$, then any singleton $\{\ast\}$ is a terminal object and any set with at least two elements has a non-identity endomorphism, e.g. by switching two elements).